# What is the length of the side of a regular hexagon and why?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

I think it is 1. Because from the Picture it Looks like that but can somebody explain me why this is so?

[image: hexagon]

Comment: How much is the angle between two line segments joining the circle's center and two adjacent vertices? Well, there you go...

Answer (score 1):

The hexacon can be partitioend into six **equilateral** triangles (three of them are shown in tge picture)

Comment: But why are they equilateral?

Comment: @RM777 they are obviously isosceles, and the one of the angles is $60^\circ$...

Comment: I see that they must be isosceles but why is one of the angle $60$?

Comment: consider $360° : 6 = ?$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a single triangle. By the argument of symmetry, the angle at the centre would be $2\pi/6$. Applying the law of cosines immediately tells you the length opposite the central angle. Let the length be $a$. $$a^2=1^2+1^2-2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot\cos(2\pi/6)\implies a=1$$